# How to present Intern positions in LinkedIn Work Experience?

Tags: internship, work-experience, linkedin

I have gained many intern positions (> 10) last years, but now, working in positions which those intern positions prepared for. 
I merged my work experience like the following in my many CVs and resume, but I cannot present the data like that in LinkedIn. 
I was paid for all those intern positions so I am keeping them in work experience. 
However, I am thinking to move them to *Relevant experience* under one title where the list of them as a list.

1. Data analyst. Company A. Location B. Time.
2. Intern. [here a list of all positions with time and location, ...]
3. Assistant. [here again a list of positions similarly as for Intern]

LinkedIn presentation: each intern position individually. Problem, taking too much space, emphasizing not so important part i.e. the current positions.

Proposition A: keep Intern positions under one title "Intern" where the specific details described in a single Description with the example

> Intern. Lorem Laboratories. Stockholm, 1/2011 - 12/2015. Bells Laboraties. Paris, 1/2016 - 6/2016. New York Physics Lab. New York, 7/2016 - 12/2016. ...

Proposition B: move some Intern fields of description to Relevant experience in some specific targets, etc applying for the law company by only emphasizing law studies in work experience, and leaving other Intern positions in Relevant experience but possibly leaving them out.

Comment: How long have you been a Data Analyst?

Comment: @MisterSortofPositive You can assume more than one year in this example.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

You believe that the quantity of intern positions plus their associated descriptions is making your LinkedIn profile "too long". I don't believe that there is such a thing. There may be a resume that is too long, but an online career profile (such as LinkedIn or Stack Overflow Careers) can not be too long. Feel free to be very verbose and list every position and a good list of your duties, accomplishments, and awards.

If you apply to positions with your online profile, no problem.

However, if you do an export, these services simply generate a PDF dump of the content. If your recipient is expecting a full and complete CV, this dump may be sufficient (although the formatting may leave something to be desired). If you can't apply online with your online profile, you can either keep an alternative format ready to go, or create it just-in-time and simply use your online profile as a reference.